# Send byte sequence over python socket

Tags: python, sockets, byte

I am trying to write a very basic server (for experimenting purposes) that listens to incoming connections on a port and when a client connects send a custom byte sequence to the client. However I am prompted with a type exception:

`TypeError: string argument without an encoding`

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 1337

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    sys.exit()

s.listen(10)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print ('Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
s.send(bytes('\x01\x02\x03'))
s.close()
```

Do I need to tell the socket somehow to send it as ascii or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to specify an encoding, like `bytes('\x01\x02\x03', 'ascii')`

Comment: `s.send(b'\x01\x02\x03')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `send` method requires a "bytes-like" object, which it looks like you are trying to pass in but aren't using the `bytes` function properly.

If you have actual binary data, like in your example, you can just create the bytes object directly:

```
s.send(b'\x01\x02\x03')
```

If you have a string (which is not the same as bytes in Python), then you have to encode the string into bytes. This can be done with the `bytes` function but you have to tell it what encoding to use. Generally ASCII or UTF-8 is used.

```
s.send(bytes('Hello world', 'ascii'))
s.send(bytes('Hello world', 'utf-8'))
```